# Emacs syntax highlight of nested backquote forms in lisp buffers

Tags: emacs, syntax-highlighting, font-lock

Is there a package for it? If not, what should I look into to create a package for it?

This package should highlight levels of parts of a nested backquote form in different colors.

```
`(a :i-am-in-level-1
    `(a :i-in-level-2
        ,(a :level-1 `(a :level-2))
        ,',(a :level-0)))
```

For example, level 0 should have no highlight, level 1 might have a light grey background, level 2 is in a darker background, and so on.

Comment: sounds like a bit of an overkill, `show-paren-mode` is more than enough for me

Comment: show-paren-mode is for parens management which is orthogonal to the problem of highlighting quote/unquote levels.

Comment: If you do come up with some code that does it, please consider submitting it for inclusion in Emacs or GNU ELPA.  I'd welcome such a feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rainbow-delimiters package does something similar for parens.  You might take inspiration from there.

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RainbowDelimiters/%22rainbow%20delimiters%22

Comment: Just finished reading its code and tricks in its code can be adapted to all kinds of nested highlighting.